# how to isolate a template in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I'm using Mustache and I have a template which is used by different HTML files.

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
{{#repo}}
  <b>{{name}}</b>
{{/repo}}
</script>
```

I would like to isolate this template in a seperate file like:

```
<script id="template" type="text/template" src="./js/template-must"></script>
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using RequireJS you can try the [text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use your backend to embed the template content into your `script[type="text/template"]`. You can save template files in `.mustache` files like many people do.

   In your html:

   [image]
2. You can text plugin of RequireJS
3. You can AJAX template content.